# How does Boto3 S3 put_object function works in python

Tags: python-2.7, boto, boto3

With Boto3:
I am using put_object() function to upload object in s3. I am using put_object() with customer encryption key parameter for server side encryption.

With Boto:
I am using upload_chunk function to upload object in s3. Here I am using aws managed keys for server side encryption and not customer given as it is not supported in API

So With Boto3 approach my program is taking more memory than Boto approach.
Please tell me how does put_object function works in boto3 for server side encryption .

is it using memory of machine for encryption on which it has called ?

should I explicitly clean data buffer which is passed as Body parameter to put_object function ?

Code:

```
def put_s3_object(self, target_key_name, data, sse_cust_key, sse_cust_key_md5): 
    ''' description: Upload file as s3 object using SSE with customer key 
    It will store s3 object in encrypted format 
    input: 
    target_key_name (#string) data(in memory string/bytes) 
    sse_cust_key (#string) 
    sse_cust_key_md5 (#string) 
    output: response 
    ''' 
    if not target_key_name: 
        raise 
    try: 
        response = self.s3_client.put_object(Bucket = self.source_bucket, Body = data, Key = target_key_name, SSECustomerAlgorithm = awsParams.CLOUD_DR_AWS_SSE_ALGO, SSECustomerKey = sse_cust_key, SSECustomerKeyMD5 = sse_cust_key_md5) 
        del data 
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError, fault: 
        raise 
    except Exception, fault: 
        raise
```

Comment: Well, there is source code :-D
https://github.com/boto/boto3

Comment: @ mootmoot:  Thanks For reply. I have directly used put_object() instead of upload_file(). This is because in boto3 upload_file() requires filename as parameter. It is not supporting data buffer as parameter. I want to send data buffer as parameter to upload in s3. 

Is it mandatory to use upload_file () ? Is it not recommend to use  put_object() directly  in boto3?

Comment: IMHO, there is a reason aws developer roll out boto3 instead of patching features to boto.  I don't see any problem of using put_object. The Body accept streaming object such as file handle, StringIO, ByteIO, etc.  If you want to upload physical file, just open() the file and pass the file handler. You just need to be careful if you want to manipulate the handler contents before putting content to put_object()

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks for the reply. 
After using put_object() with server side encryption parameters my memory usage goes high for 5-6 hours.
Please inform me if I am missing any parameters in put_object () function call

Comment: @mootmoot  Should I need to call any cleanup() which will free my consumed memory ? 
Is there any parameter in put_object () call which does cleanup of consumed memory?

Comment: I afraid this is OS cache behavior. If you put_object frequently, and the memory footprints doesn't increase over time, then maybe it is safe to wait for OS garbage collection.  Otherwise, You can check out some suggestion here.   http://askubuntu.com/questions/584095/is-there-any-application-or-command-that-cleans-the-memory-like-ccleaner-in-wind

Comment: @mootmoot  What is the use of 'CacheControl' parameter in put_object () call? What should be the value for 'CacheControl' parameter in put_object () call? Is it something which related to memory footprints ?

Comment: Cache_control has nothing to do with RAM usage. http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/amazon-s3--how-to-set-cache-control-header-for-s3-object.html

Comment: @mootmoot Thanks. So what would be problem with RAM usage while using put_object () function call ? OR is there any way if I want to use boto3's upload_file() call with data buffer parameter instead of  filename ?

Comment: I can't answer that since I am not the developer nor going diagnose the code in the near future.  Maybe you can experiment with multpartupload/ upload_file and use s3 transfer to set the threshold size and hope it will control the memory footprints, but nothing guaranteed. http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/_modules/boto3/s3/transfer.html

Alternate solution is launch SPOT instance that cost a fraction of typical instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Boto3 put_object(), We can go with set_contents_to_string() and get_contents_as_string() functions from boto. 
These calls also supports server side encryption with customer keys(SSE-C). we just need to give all keys information in headers

For more details 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerSideEncryptionCustomerKeys.html